# Prove that $xax^{-1} = yay^{-1}$ iff $C_a x = C_a y$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to prove an exercise in a book on abstract algebra I am reading. The setup is that for any element $a$ of a group $G$, we define the centraliser $C_a = \{ x \in G : xa = ax \}$, so all elements that commute with $a$. Now, we must prove that if $xax^{-1} = yay^{-1}$, that $C_a x = C_a y$.

My progress is that $xax^{-1} = yay^{-1}$ implies that $(y^{-1}x)a = a(y^{-1}x)$, so $y^{-1}x \in C_a$. However, this proves that $C_a y^{-1} = C_a x^{-1}$, which I do not think is equivalent to $C_a x = C_a y$ (as $C_a x = C_a x^{-1}$ is not generally true). Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: I suggest that you check this out in an easy case: For instance look at $G=S_3$, $a=(12)$, $x=(123)$, $y=(23)$. [I read my perms left-to-right].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you need to show $C_ax=C_ay$? I think it must be $xC_a=yC_a ...$

Comment: Absolutely. It comes from writing conjugates "the wrong way". The hypothesis ought to have been $x^{-1}ax=y^{-1}ay$ to achieve $C_ax=C_ay$.

Comment: @ancient mathematician, this is entirely correct!

Comment: That is definitely what the question says, but after working out @ancient mathematician's example, I do believe this has to be the version the question intended. Thanks for the confirmation!